# Python Tkinter Custom Window

Tags: python, coding-style, tkinter, code-structure

I have this simple `Tkinter Custom Window`. I am a beginner and only learnt tkinter a few months ago. I have no experience in real software development. So, I would like to know if the way it was coded is acceptable? I know that when i say **acceptable** , it could mean a lot of things. I just want to know what are the things i should improve in my coding style & the way i think?

```
import Tkinter as tk

''' Creating Tkinter Tk instance '''
class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)
        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.StartMove)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.StopMove)
        self.bind("<B1-Motion>", self.OnMotion)
        self.Init()
        self.Layout()
        self.AddButtons()

    ''' Setting Main Tk window size & styles '''
    def Init(self):
        self.geometry("1280x700+0+0")
        self.overrideredirect(True)
        self['background'] = '#201F29'
        self['highlightthickness'] = 2
        self['relief'] = 'groove'

    '''Layout of the Tk window'''
    def Layout(self):
        self.exitmenu = tk.Frame(self)
        self.exitmenu.place(x = 1217,  y = 0)
        self.container = tk.Frame(self,width = 1268,height = 648 , relief = 'flat',bd = 0)
        self.container.place(x = 5,y = 40)

    ''' Adding Exit button and Minimize button to the Tk window'''
    def AddButtons(self):
        self.minibutton = tk.Button(self.exitmenu,text = '0',font=('webdings',8,'bold'),relief = 'flat' , command = self.minimize )
        self.minibutton.pack(side = 'left')
        self.exitbutton = tk.Button(self.exitmenu,text = 'r',font=('webdings',8),relief = 'flat' ,bg = '#DB6B5A', command = self.destroy )
        self.exitbutton.pack(side = 'left')

    def minimize(self):
        self.overrideredirect(False)
        self.wm_state('iconic')
        self.overrideredirect(True)

    '''Methods for moving window frame'''
    def StartMove(self, event):
        self.x = event.x
        self.y = event.y

    def StopMove(self, event):
        self.x = None
        self.y = None

    def OnMotion(self, event):
        x1 = self.x
        y1 = self.y
        x2 = event.x
        y2 = event.y
        deltax = x2 - x1
        deltay = y2 - y1
        a = self.winfo_x() + deltax
        b = self.winfo_y() + deltay
        self.geometry("+%s+%s" % (a, b))


def Main():
    app = Application()
    app.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Comment: You used the `coding-style` tag; the tag wiki page says: *Note: if you want a code review, do not post it here, but post it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.*. I suggest you follow that advice; Stack Overflow is aimed at helping you fix coding problems, not coding style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) Install and run one or all of [PEP8 checker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8/1.4.6), [pyFlakes](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes), [pyChecker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyChecker/0.8.12), [pylint](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint/1.0.0).

The first thing that stands out is that docstrings are supposed to be within the function rather than before it - then they become a part of the function code and can be accessed by help.

Comment: I think you forgot to mention `autopep8` :)

Comment: @Xilpex - autopep8 saves some work but doesn't usually **teach** the user to get things right in the first place.